# jquery file upload with ajax with php

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'functions.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: i am new in jquery ajax. i use this method for upload. i tried and tried but i cannot. jquey throw error. please help me what is the problem here.php code is not working when i use this ajax upload method. thanks

Comment: What is the specific error? Always include those messages, they are very informative. The code shown looks fine so long as path to functions.php is correct from current page

Comment: if ($_FILES['picture']['name'] !='') {
 $filename = $_FILES['picture']['name'];
 $extension = pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 $valid_extension = array("jpg","jpeg","png","gif");
 if(in_array($extension,$valid_extension)){
  $new_name = rand() .".".$extension;
  $path = "images/".$new_name;
  if(move_uploaded_file($FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $path)){
   echo'<img src="'.$path.'" /><br><br><button>delete</button>';
  }
 }else {
  echo '<script>alert("invalid file formate")</script>';
 }

}else {
  echo '<script>alert("invalid file formate")</script>';
}

Comment: php script and it show that
Undefined array key "picture" in E:\xampp\htdocs\subForm\functions.php on line 3